# Is there a way to import external custom API to Bluemix without using API management service? If yes, How?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, ibm-datapower, ibm-api-management

I am trying to import a custom API that I created. Is there a way to use it straight from IBM-datapower without importing it into Bluemix catalog using API management service?

Comment: What version is it in, DataPower XML, Swagger?
If you have a local DataPower there is no need for Bluemix...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean have the API accessible from Bluemix catalog as other current services?

To appear in the catalog you need to add a [User-Provided Service](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html#create) or create a [Service Broker](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/api.html#api-overview). Both options are documented in Cloud Foundry docs.

The quickest way is using User-Provided Service because it doesn't require programming. But the credentials of the service are not dynamic and the service will appear into your organization/space dashboard, not into the general catalog.

The Service Broker requires programming but it is dynamic and appears in the catalog to everybody.

The power of using API Management service, is that it implements automatic Service Brokers to integrate the selected API into de generic catalog without needing any custom programming.

Check if User-Provided Service option could fit your needs...